# .net core web application as desktop app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

here is a scenario.
we have some client that work on remove area so we want to give them distributed version of app where they can operate offline without worrying about network.

so it will work like offline and online and need a capability to push updates whenever there is patch.

please let me know if you can enlighten me.
thank you.

Comment: Is your web app hosted somewhere, and you only need a client shell? Or do you need the client to run the .Net Web App itself? If your app is hosted and you only need a native-looking client shell, please check out my answer below. However, if you need to bundle and distribute the .Net Web App itself, then that requires a different technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). This tool allows you to create and distribute cross-platform web applications that run in a native shell, complete with native installers, update mechanisms, etc. Some very interesting applications are being published as Electron apps, such as Visual Studio Code, Slack, Atom, etc.